# Angular 9 reactive forms: dynamically added validator not showing error message

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to add validation to one of the my form fields based on a condition

```
this.formGroup = new FormBuilder().group({
      ....
      companyName: [''],
      ....
 });
```

Here is the snippet to add the dynamic validator

```
this.formGroup.get('personType').valueChanges.pipe(
      tap((personType: string) => {
       
        if (personType === '1') {
            this.formGroup.get('companyName').setValidators(Validators.required);
          } else {
            this.formGroup.get('companyName').clearValidators();
          }

          this.formGroup.get('companyName').updateValueAndValidity();
      })
    ).subscribe();
```

But when I submit form I am facing two issues:

1. Even I enter a value in `companyName` field it's not showing in the `formgroup.value` object (still it's an empty string)
2. The validation error message is not showing but I can see the error is set in the controls

   ```
    companyName: FormControl
        asyncValidator: null
        errors:
            required: true
        pristine:true
        touched:false
   ```

**HTML**

```
<form name="property" #formDirective="ngForm" class="form-example" [formGroup]="formGroup">
.....
<input  formControlName="companyName" />
....
</form>
```

Comment: Can you share the html part?

Comment: @MarcellKiss updated HTML

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: @iambatman Where do you print your errors? Can you paste that part of the html

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic validation:

```
dynamicValidation(): void {
    let control1 = null;
    control1 = this.formGroup.get('companyName');
      control1.setValidators([Validators.pattern(this.nameREGEX), Validators.minLength(this.minLength)]);
  control1.updateValueAndValidity();

  }
```

Comment: My solution does the same I can't see a difference

Answer (score 0):

Faced the Same Problem while dynamically validating. I Changed the button used to submit the form into type="submit" or use (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()" binding. both worked.